# Syntax Error with Templated Cuda Kernel Launch

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, cuda

I'm getting an unexpected syntax error after refactoring some CUDA code and I can't figure out why the compiler is having an issue.

I'm getting the following error:

```
$ cmake --build . --target test_GS_basic
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  gtest.vcxproj -> C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\lib\Debug\gtest.lib
  gtest_main.vcxproj -> C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\lib\Debug\gtest_main.lib
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\..\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.cu...
  
  C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\src\gram_schmidt\tests>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=\"compute_86,compute_86\" -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=\"sm_86,compute_86\" --use-local-env -ccbin " 
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\utils -IC:\repositories 
  \gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\math_basics -I"C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\include" -I"C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\_deps\googletest-src\goo 
  gletest" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++17 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"$<1:/W4" -D"/WX>" -D"$<0:-Wall" -D"-Wextra" -D"-Wpedantic>" -D"CMA 
  KE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D"$<1:/W4" -D"/WX>" -D"$<0:-Wall" -D"-Wextra" -D"-Wpedantic>" -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdtest_GS_basic.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o test_GS_basic.dir\Debug\test_GS_basic.obj "C:\ 
  \repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.cu"
  test_GS_basic.cu
C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\gram_schmidt_curator_v2.hh(186): error C2059: syntax error: '<' [C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.vcxproj]
  C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\gram_schmidt_curator_v2.hh(162): note: while compiling class template member function 'void GS_curator_v2<float>::initialize_basis(std::vector<working_vector<float>,std::allocator<working_vector<float>>> &,bool)'    
  C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.cu(69): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void GS_curator_v2<float>::initialize_basis(std::vector<working_vector<float>,std::allocator<working_vector<float>>> &,bool)' being 
   compiled
  C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.cu(67): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'GS_curator_v2<float>' being compiled
C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\gram_schmidt_curator_v2.hh(191): error C2059: syntax error: '<' [C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.7.targets(790,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=\"compute_86,compute_86\"  
-gencode=arch=compute_86,code=\"sm_86,compute_86\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests -IC:\r 
epositories\gram_schmidt\src\utils -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt -IC:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\math_basics -I"C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\include" -I"C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\_deps\googletest-src\googletest" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++17 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS  
-D"$<1:/W4" -D"/WX>" -D"$<0:-Wall" -D"-Wextra" -D"-Wpedantic>" -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D"$<1:/W4" -D"/WX>" -D"$<0:-Wall" -D"-Wextra" -D"-Wpedantic>" -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdtest_GS_basic.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb /FS /Z 
i /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o test_GS_basic.dir\Debug\test_GS_basic.obj "C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.cu"" exited with code 2. [C:\repositories\gram_schmidt\build\src\gram_schmidt\tests\test_GS_basic.vcxproj]
```

The function the compiler is complaining about is this one:

```
template<typename T>
void GS_curator_v2<T>::initialize_basis(std::vector<working_vector<T>>& input_set, bool overwrite)
{
    sync_gpu_to_cpu();

    assert(input_set.size() != 0);
    assert(input_set[0].vect_len == k_state_len);
    assert(m_cpu_basis_block.capacity >= input_set.size());
    
    if (m_cpu_basis_block.size > 0 && !overwrite) {
        // Overwriting basis set without meaning too can be extrememly dangerous
        assert(false);
    }

    // Allocate temporary space for input vector on GPU, all data will be copied to basis array.
    std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&cudaFree)> dev_vect_data{wrap_cuda_malloc<T>(k_state_length), cudaFree};

    static const unsigned int num_threads = 512;
    size_t shared_bytes = sizeof(double) * num_threads;
    for (size_t ind = 0; ind < input_set.size(); ++ind) {
        working_vector<T> input = input_set[ind];
        cudaMemcpy(dev_vect_data.get(), input.vect, sizeof(T)*k_state_length, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        input.vect = dev_vect_data.get();

        if (ind == 0) { 
            // Clear out the old basis when setting the first basis vector
            initialize_basis_kern<T><<<1, num_threads, shared_bytes>>>(input, m_dev_basis_block.get(), m_dev_basis_vectors.get());
            GPU_ERR_CHK( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
        }
        else {
            // All subsequent vectors in the set get appended
            append_basis_kern<T><<<1, num_threads, shared_bytes>>>(input, m_dev_basis_block.get(), m_dev_basis_vectors.get());
            GPU_ERR_CHK( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
        }
    }

    sync_gpu_to_cpu();
}
```

Specifically this line in the above function: `initialize_basis_kern<T><<<1, num_threads, shared_bytes>>>(input, m_dev_basis_block.get(), m_dev_basis_vectors.get());`

The initialize_basis_kern function looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__
void initialize_basis_kern(working_vector<T> g_input, state_array<T>* g_basis_block, working_vector<T>* g_basis_all)
{
    // Clear all basis vectors
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        g_basis_block->size = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // Set the first basis vector which will properly normalize and update size
    append_basis<T>(g_input, g_basis_block, g_basis_all);
}
```

And append_basis function is this:

```
template<typename T>
__device__
void append_basis(working_vector<T> g_input, state_array<T>* g_basis_block, working_vector<T>* g_basis_all)
{
    assert(g_basis_block->size < g_basis_block->capacity);

    working_vector<T>& new_basis = g_basis_all[g_basis_block->size];
    double mag = vect_mag_cuda(g_input.vect, g_input.vect_len);
    vect_scal_div_cuda(g_input.vect, g_input.vect_len, mag, new_basis.vect);

    // Set metadata for new basis vector
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        new_basis.orig_key = g_input.orig_key;
        new_basis.vect_len = g_input.vect_len;
        new_basis.ID = g_input.ID;
        new_basis.magnitude = mag;
        new_basis.dependent = false;
        new_basis.last_basis_ID = -1;

        // Resize basis block structure to only 1 valid vector
        g_basis_block->size++;
    }
}
```

The "working_vector" structure is this:

```
template<typename T>
struct working_vector {
    T* vect{nullptr}; /**< Pointer to vector array somewhere in memory. (CPU or GPU)*/
    size_t vect_len{0}; /**< Length of vector array.*/
    uint32_t orig_key{uint32_t{-1}}; /**< Key to recover full original file address information.*/
    int32_t ID{-1}; /**< Unique identifier for this vector.*/
    double magnitude{0}; /**< Magnitude of vector array the last time it was processed in the GPU kernel.*/
    bool dependent{false}; /**< Dependency flag used to check when residuals can be eliminated in processing. N/A for basis vectors.*/
    int32_t last_basis_ID{-1}; /**< Tracks which basis vectors a residual has been processed against. N/A for basis vectors.*/
};
```

I've checked this code dozens of times and tried to tweak the kernel launch by hardcoding the template type, switching to passing by pointer for all inputs, with no luck.

There doesn't appear to be a syntax error but maybe there is something I overlooked during the template expansion.

Any ideas?

It's worth noting that I have other CUDA kernels with similar inputs and templatization and the compiler has no issues with those.

**Edited 2024-01-12**
Included full error message

Comment: You are not compiling with the correct compiler. If you have kernel launch syntax, it must be compiled with nvcc

Comment: I'm compiling with NVCC through cmake

Comment: But the error in your question is an MSVC generated error, not an nvcc error

Comment: I edited to include the full terminal output. It looks like nvcc.exe is being called unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my question this morning by creating a simplified main application instead of google test code to exercise the lines that caused the issue. Turns out nothing was wrong with those lines as all.

The error was in this line inside `initialize_basis` function:

```
assert(input_set[0].vect_len == k_state_len);
```

`k_state_len` variable doesn't exist, it should be `k_state_length`. It was a simple typo on my part that the compiler didn't catch. Instead I guess the combination of using google test with cuda and templates caused it to throw a compiler error on a totally unrelated line.

Did some more digging and I have a theory. At the top of my test code file I define some constants.

```
static const int k_state_len {3000};
static const int k_input_limit {2000};
static const int k_basis_limit {200};
static const int k_max_indep_vect {100};
static const int k_max_depend_vect {1000};
```

These are at file scope in my test code source file so they shouldn't leak anywhere. Except all of my core code is templated so the necessary instantiation gets added to the source file it's used in. I'm guessing this means that my file scope constants in `test_GS_basic.cu` were valid in any of the templated instantiations and my typo happened to be one of them. So the compiler thought that the variable was valid.

I don't fully understand how the compiler processed this but it seems to be a weird edge case where it thought a variable was valid when it actually wasn't and that caused issues later in the compilation process.